# How can I avoid a longtable to be counted?

Tags: longtable, counters

I use longtables to add Notes to my document. These notes shall not be counted. Can I tell longtable this (similar to `\chapter*` instead of `\chapter`)?

Comment: `\caption*`?  Otherwise please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: `\caption*` but then also `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` after the table to put the table counter back. (the fact that that is needed is a "feature")

Comment: `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` was what I was looking for. Thanks.